# Как обновить базы pkg и apt в Termux

Tags: bash, termux, apt

Пользуюсь Termux довольно давно и недавно столкнулся с проблемой - походу, репозитории с которых `apt` и `pkg` берут данные, стали неактуальны.

Вот сама ошибка:

```
$ pkg install python-pip
Testing the available mirrors:
[*] https://dl.bintray.com/termux/termux-packages-24: bad
[*] https://grimler.se/termux-packages-24: ok
[*] https://main.termux-mirror.ml: bad
[*] https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-packages-24: ok
Picking mirror: https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-packages-24
Hit:1 https://termux.mentality.rip/termux-packages-24 stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games InRelease
Ign:3 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science InRelease
Err:4 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release
  404  Not Found
Err:5 https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/game-packages-24 games Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
E: The repository 'https://dl.bintray.com/grimler/science-packages-24 science Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Metadata integrity can't be verified, repository is disabled now.
N: Possible cause: repository is under maintenance or down (wrong sources.list URL?).
```

Comment: Пробовали в терминале сначала `pkg update`, затем `apt update`?

Comment: С pkg там свои проблемы. Ему нужен openssl, для установки которого нужен... openssl

Comment: Сейчас обновлю сам Termux. Как я понял, проблема в неактуальности версии с PlayMarket